# To show sequence $a_n$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $a_n$ such 
$$
a_2 \leq a_4 \leq a_6 \le \cdots\cdots \leq a_5 \leq a_3 \leq a_1
$$
and a sequence ${b_n}$, where $b_n = a_{2n-1} - a_{2n}$ converges to $0$, then show that $a_n$ is convergent.

I can see that sequence $a_n$ has two subsequences (odd terms and even terms) which are decreasing. But any hints to get me furthure? Thanks.

Comment: The odd sequence is decreasing and bounded from below, thus converges to some $a$. The condition on $b_n$ just shows that the even term would also be closed to $a$ as $n$ large.

Comment: @John Odd sequence is decreasing but how can u say that it is bounded from below?

Comment: From what you wrote I thought it is bounded by $a_2$?

Comment: @John how can condition on b says about even terms ?

Comment: Are you familiar with Cauchy sequences and completeness, i.e. do you know that in $\mathbb{R}$ every Cauchy sequence converges?

Comment: Yes with cauchy sequences

Comment: @J.A.L Are u pointing that $b_n$ is a cauchy sequence as it converges .also $a_{2n-1}$ converges bcos its bounded and decreasing .

Comment: @godonichia: Use the following: If $n = 2k$ is even, then $|a_n - a| \leq |a- a_{2k-1}| + |a_{2k-1} - a_{2k}|$. Both terms are small.

Comment: @godonichia No, I was pointing that from the inequality and the convergence of $b_n$ it follows that the sequence itself is Cauchy and thus converges.

Comment: @John why have u claimed that $a_n$ converges to a ?

Comment: @J.A.L Sorry i have still not got point

Comment: Let $L=\lim a_{2n}$ and $R=\lim a_{2n-1}$. $L$ exists because $\{a_{2n}\}$ is an increasing sequence that's bounded (by $a_1$ say); $R$ exists for similar reasons. Can you prove $L\le R$? Can you then use the assumption on $b_n$ to prove that $L=R$?

Comment: @GregMartin $L\leq$R bcos even terms are less than equal to odd terms .there's theorem for this i think

Comment: @GregMartin giveb $b_n$ is convergent .  so limit as n goes to infinity $a_{2n-1}$ - $a_{2n}$ goes to zero which implies $a_{2n-1}$ = $a_{2n}$ . If i take lim $a_{2n-1}$ = L so lim of $a_{2n}$  has to be equal to L.  Thus i have two subsequences which converge to L . so $a_n$ converges to L . AM I RIGHT?

Comment: @godonichia: I am claiming that the odd sequence converges to $a$.